# How to test the front end performance of web page with a user token

Tags: performance-testing

I have a web application where the user needs to enter the user name and logging to the web page.  I need to do a front end performance tests in the pages which loaded after user logging on to the web site.

After login to the web page, web page uses a user token to handle the uses session. Is there any tool/way to do front end performance test for this type of scenario.

I tried with the [www.webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org) but analysis stop from the login page it won't go to the page after the login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to use protractor that helps you in this. For reference kindly go this [page](https://www.protractortest.org/#).
Basically, what it did for you, it runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would. It's an end-to-end test framework for Angular and AngularJS applications. Also able to perform testing on other framework too.

For more testing frameworks. kindly go [here](https://www.guru99.com/frontend-testing.html).